# ANDROID using a non standard SIP port

Tags: android, sip, voip

i'm tring to use Android SIP Sample App. My problem is that is i try to change default port (5060) with my server port 443 i've these errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: incorrect port arugment: 443
```

I use for change port:

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, server);
builder.setPort(443);
```

Please can someone help me?!

Comment: Check here :-http://code.google.com/p/sip2peer/downloads/detail?name=Android-Sip2Peer-1.0.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, uri.getHost())
builder.setPort(uri.getPort());
builder.build();
```